# $_POST command doesnt recognise multiple-choice image checkbox value

Tags: php, html, forms, image, checkbox

My Goal: when a user clicks on "submit", I want to get all the selected values (aka "attraction types") (when a picture is clicked, it should work like a checkbox). The CSS works properly, but when i reach the php file it ignores my selection and says "No Atrtype", acting like no value was chosen.

I am new to php (and coding in general) and have tried to re-order the divs, use ***"isset"*** in php and change the variable names (and a lot more), yet it was to no avail. I would appreciate some help here.

*most classes have to do with css attributes , so please ignore css for this question's sake.*

php:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  // collect value of input field
  
$atrtype1    = (isset($_POST['atrtype'])    ? $_POST['atrtype']    : '');
  if (empty($atrtype)) {
    echo "No Atrtype";
  } 
  else{
      echo $atrtype1;
  }
}
```

html:

```
<form action="get_triptypes.php" method="post" class="home_search_form" id="home_search_form">
    <div id="beaches" class="choice_item">
        <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
            <input name="atrtype[0]" type="checkbox" id="beaches" value="beaches" style="display:none;"/>
            <div class="choice_image">
                <label for="beaches"> <img src="images/destination_1.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="250" onclick="this.style.opacity = 0.4" ondblclick="this.style.opacity = 1"> </label>
            </div>
            <div class="choice_title">
                <h1 style="font-size:50px;">Beaches</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Trip -->
    <div id="history" class="choice_item">
        <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
            <input name="atrtype[1]" type="checkbox" id="history" value="history" style="display:none;"/>
            <div class="choice_image">
                <label for="history"> <img src="images/history0.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="200" onclick="this.style.opacity = 0.4; " ondblclick="this.style.opacity = 1"> </label>
                <div class="choice_title">
                    <h1 style="font-size:40px;">Historic Sites</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Trip -->
    <div id="themeparks" class="choice_item">
        <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
            <input name="atrtype[2]" type="checkbox" id="themeparks" value="themeparks" style="display:none;"/>
            <div class="choice_image">
                <label for - "themeparks"> <img src="images/amusementpark.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="250" onclick="this.style.opacity = 0.4" ondblclick="this.style.opacity = 1"> </label>
                <div class="choice_title">
                    <h1 style="font-size:40px;">Theme Parks</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Trip -->
    <div id="nature" class="choice_item">
        <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
            <input name="atrtype[3]" type="checkbox" id="nature" value="nature" style="display:none;"/>
            <div class="choice_image">
                <label for="nature"><img src="images/nature.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="250" onclick="this.style.opacity = 0.4; Add(this);" ondblclick="this.style.opacity = 1;"></label>
                <div class="choice_title">
                    <h1 style="font-size:50px;">Nature</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Trip -->
    <div id="shopping" class="choice_item">
        <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
            <input name="atrtype[4]" type="checkbox" id="shopping" value="shopping" style="display:none;"/>
            <div class="choice_image">
                <label for="shopping"><img src="images/shopping.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="250" onclick="this.style.opacity = 0.4" ondblclick="this.style.opacity = 1"></label>
                <div class="choice_title">
                    <h1 style="font-size:40px;">Shopping Malls</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Trip -->
    <div id="food" class="choice_item">
        <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
            <input name="atrtype[5]" type="checkbox" id="food" value="food" style="display:none;"/>
            <div class="choice_image">
                <label for="food"><img src="images/food.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="250" onclick="this.style.opacity = 0.4" ondblclick="this.style.opacity = 1"></label>
                <div class="choice_title">
                    <h1 style="font-size:40px;">Foodie attractions</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Trip -->
    <div id="cities" class="choice_item">
        <div class="choice_image">
            <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
                <input name="atrtype[6]" type="checkbox" id="cities" value="cities" style="display:none;"/>
                <label for="cities"> <img src="images/oldtown.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="250" onclick="this.style.opacity = 0.4" ondblclick="this.style.opacity = 1"></label>
                <div class="choice_title">
                    <h1 style="font-size:40px;">Old towns</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Trip -->
    <div id="culture" class="choice_item">
        <div class="choice_image">
            <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
                <input name="atrtype[7]" type="checkbox" id="culture" value="culture" style="display:none;"/>
                <label for="culture"><img src="images/dance.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="250" onclick="this.style.opacity = 0.4;" ondblclick="this.style.opacity = 1"></label>
                <div class="choice_title">
                    <h1 style="font-size:30px;">Cultural Activities</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row load_more_row">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="submit" class="button home_search_button"/>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: HTML basics: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document, which you are violating in multiple places here.

Comment: thank you, I may not have noticed that.

Comment: Clicking on the label elements _would_ toggle the state of those checkboxes correctly - if it wasn’t for the fact, that you have each of your checkboxes wrapped into a div element that shares the same respective ID. Because of this mistake, that does not happen, and so you are always submitting your form with no checkboxes checked at all.

Comment: Also check your closing </div>'s. Indenting your code correctly helps identify if/where you get mismatched <div> </div>tags. You appear to have 4 too many where they are all in the same column (near the end) and a missing one just before the </form>.

Comment: Your PHP is treating the `$atrtype1` as if it's a single value, it's not, its an *array of values*. Try `print_r($_POST['atrtype'])` to see what the data actually is and adjust your code accordingly. You can't `echo` out an array.

Comment: @CBroe I fixed the multiple - ids issue but it doesnt work properly yet, maybe the issue lies within the divs. Ill try to reorganise the code and see if it helps.

Comment: works!! :D thank you so much. apparently the right values were given. The issue was when i tried to "echo" it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous issues here:

Your PHP is treating the `$atrtype1` as if it's a single value, it's not, its an *array of values*. Try `print_r($_POST['atrtype'])` to see what the data actually is and adjust your code accordingly. You can't `echo` out an array.

You have a typo:

```
$atrtype1    = ...
if (empty($atrtype)) {
```

These are two different variables!

Also, stop using `==` and improve your coding style by using `===` full type-casting qualifiers

## Fixed:

```
// Why do you even need another variable?   
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
  
   $_POST['atrtype'] = array_filter($_POST['atrtype']); // remove empty values
   if (count($_POST['atrtype']) < 1) {
      echo "No Atrtype";
   } 
   else{
      echo print_r($_POST['atrtype']); //output all values in the array. 
   }

}
```

Your processing logic is a mess of arrays and strings, you really need to take a clean sheet of paper and judge what you're doing from the start, again. I can't advise much on this without understanding your full intentions and logic flow.